# Magento - PayPal IPN configuration

Tags: url, magento, module, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set up a web shop using Magento (v. 1.5) and one of my payment options is PayPal standard payments. Everything works fine so far but now I would like to trigger a script on another server by using the IPN URL from PayPal when a payment is received.

The PayPal account is also used for other web platforms and it has the correct IPN URL for the script already set up in the account configuration. However, the Magento module seems to overwrite this URL and always sets it to "http://myshop.com/paypal/ipn/" when someone buys something in the Magento shop.

My problem is that I can not find any possibilities to change this behaviour in Magento itself. The backend module configuration offers nothing in that direction and I also looked into the IPN model and controller files in the core directories (Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php and Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php).

It has to be possible to change the IPN URL but I'm out of ideas at this point... so I'd be very thankful for any helpful hints!

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The IPN notification URL is set in `Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard::getStandardCheckoutFormFields`:

```
$api->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
```

The function is called by `Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect`, so you can override either the model or the block to change/remove the URL. But keep in mind that Magento needs the IPN notification to update order status etc.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. Updates for each order are not necessary for me because they are handled by another system.